# SUBTRACT two columns SUM, then SUBTRACT the result and SUM the result to show minimum quantity

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

Is a little complicated the question, but I need to show the SUM of SUBTRACT two columns SUM and then SUBTRACT the result.

Right now I have the result (1,1,1) when the minimum quantity is below of "x" value for each product but right now show me three buttons(because there are 3 products with below of minimum quantity) with the minimum quantity legend and I need show just one button with per example 3 minimum quantity..

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(existencia - vendido) AS texist, alert_cantidad FROM PRODUCTOS GROUP BY cod";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $texist = $row['texist'];
    $alerta = $row['alert_cantidad'];
    $result2 = $texist - $alerta;
    if ($result2 < 0) { 
        echo "<li><a class='btn btn-info' href='alertProduct.php'>
        <i class='glyphicons glyphicons-circle_exclamation_mark'></i>
        " .$result2." minima cantidad
        </a></li>";
    }
}
```

Here a capture with the issue:

[image]

Here what I really need to show:

[image]

Comment: `count($result2)` doen't do anything. you don't capture the return value, so `if ($result2 < 0) is basically doing `if (Array < 2)`.

Comment: @MarcB yes I just prove it and I forgot to delete that part. I already delete that line, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `SUM` query in a subquery, and then use `COUNT(*)` in the main query to get the number that match your criteria:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM (SELECT SUM(existencia - vendido) AS texist, alert_cantidad 
              FROM PRODUCTOS 
              GROUP BY cod) AS x
        WHERE texist < alert_cantidad";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count2 = $row['count'];
echo "<li><a class='btn btn-info' href='alertProduct.php'>
    <i class='glyphicons glyphicons-circle_exclamation_mark'></i>
    " .$result2." minima cantidad
    </a></li>";
```

Comment: Thank you, that sentence show me what I needed, just I need fix this part : `$result = $conn->query($sql):` to `$result = $conn->query($sql);`